# Template argument deduction failure due to inconsistent constness

Tags: c++, c++14, constants, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following (which [doesn't compile](https://ideone.com/BMudmh), but we'll fix that in a moment):

```
void foo(const int *n) { }

template <typename ...Args>
void bar(void (*func)(Args...), Args... args) { func(args...); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 42;
    bar(foo, &n);
}
```

The template function `bar()` takes a function pointer to call and a parameter pack of arguments to pass to it. gcc 7.4.0 diagnoses the following error:

```
test.cpp:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:11:16: note:   inconsistent parameter pack deduction with ‘const int*’ and ‘int*’
```

So clearly, the [type deduction rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) are not relaxed enough to allow `const T*` to be deduced when both `const T*` and `T*` are observed. OK, fine. This is easy enough to [fix with a cast](https://ideone.com/r144Dy):

```
bar(foo, static_cast<const int *>(&n));
```

But this is ugly. C++17 has [`std::as_const()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) which makes it a little less ugly (`&std::as_const(n)`) but in my current project I'm limited to C++14, sadface.

**Q**: Is there a way to rearrange this code so that type deduction succeeds without explicitly specifying the template parameters for `bar()` and without casting to resolve the ambiguous constness? Thinking outside the box is allowed, as long as I can pass a function pointer and its arguments to a template function!

Comment: You might define `const int n = 42; bar(foo, &n);` instead.

Comment: @vahancho In my real use-case, `n` is a variable of `struct` and must not be `const`. I can obviously create a separate `const` reference to it but the point of the question is to avoid going out of my way like that.

Comment: You need two parameter packs. One to deduce the parameters to the function getting passed in, and a 2nd parameter pack for the arguments being forwarded. SFINAE can be used to prevent unwanted overload resolution instead of a compilation error, in case of invalid arguments. P.S. Your "doesn't compile" version (in the question itself) actually compiles, because it's identical to the version that does compile.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks, good suggestion and I've "fixed" (or rather broke, hehe) the initial code snippet in the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can separate the deduction for the function pointer and the parameters:

```
void foo(const int *n) {}

template <typename... FArgs, typename... Args>
void bar(void (*func)(FArgs...), Args&&... args) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = 42;
    bar(foo, &n);
}
```

But at that point I wonder why the function pointer need to be decompose. Why not accept any callable?

```
void foo(const int *n) {}

template <typename F, typename... Args>
void bar(F func, Args&&... args) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = 42;
    bar(foo, static_cast<const int *>(&n));
    bar([](int const*){}, &n);
}
```

Also, remember that C++17 offers [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke):

```
std::invoke(foo, &n);
```